# Can you tell when a body's internal energy was acquired by reusing work or by transferring heat?

Tags: thermodynamics

Can you tell when a body's internal energy was acquired by reusing work or by transferring heat?

Comment: What do you mean by "reusing work"?

Comment: What do you mean by "internal energy" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the body's state now and at some previous time, you can tell if heat or irreversible work was involved to change the state. You calculate the change in the body's *entropy*. Entropy is a function of state, and if you know what sort of body you're dealing with and how many moles of substance it comprises, the calculation may be possible. The standard example is an ideal gas, for which, with the usual notation,
$$\text{Entropy change}, S_B-S_A=nc_v\ln\frac{T_B}{T_A} + nR\ln\frac{V_B}{V_A}$$
If you calculate the entropy change for a reversible adiabatic change (for which $TV^{\gamma -1} =\text{constant}$) you will find it to be zero. This indicates that the change of state involved only reversible work and no heat. But for *any* change of state a positive entropy change indicates that some heat or irreversible work was involved. You might like to see what the formula yields for an *isothermal* expansion.

There is a simple microscopic interpretation of the different state changes brought about quasi-statically by reversible work or by heat. Work changes the energy levels of the system; heat changes the populations of the levels.

Comment: The first half of the answer can be read to mean that one can inspect a body and determine whether it was heated by heat transfer or irreversible work, which is not true. It can only be determined whether reversible work was used or not.

Comment: @JánLalinský  If we know that the body's internal energy has risen (though I didn't specifically say that we did) and we know that reversible work was not used, surely we know that heat or irreversible work *was* used? I'm confused.

Comment: Yes that is true. But which one of the two ways was used cannot be determined.